# Languages 'supersite' on Codidact

Tags: discussion, arabic

There's a [proposal for a Languages site](https://meta.codidact.com/questions/276701) on [Codidact](https://codidact.org/), a Q&A site created by users who left StackExchange, that I've proposed taking the idea from Rebecca Stones's [Languages.SE proposal on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29986/163293). Like the Area 51 proposal, this Codidact site is aimed to include questions on any human language, including Arabic. Seeing that there have been many Arabic proposals on Area 51 and all of them have failed, and noting the lack of response from SE about Languages.SE, perhaps you will be interested in Codidact's Languages site. Codidact is ["currently only creating sites that have a community already interested"](https://meta.codidact.com/questions/276139#answer-276141), so if enough people show support for this proposal on Codidact, this will have a real chance of becoming realised.

Comment: (PS. When I heard about it, I suggested mentioning this here, as there's users who have Arabic questions [and I'd guess Urdu and Farsi too].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site was launched just recently: https://languages.codidact.com/